# Une nuance entre « aurait de quoi démoraliser » et « démoraliserait »

Tags: expressions

> La situation **aurait de quoi démoraliser** n'importe quel scientifique.
>
> La situation **démoraliserait** n'importe quel scientifique.

What does the phrasing « aurait de quoi démoraliser » denote that simply saying « démoraliserait » doesn’t ?

**UPDATE:**

1. In the following sentence, is the expression « aurait de quoi + infinitive » used in a similar way?

   > Il ne faudrait pas que ... ou il y **aurait de quoi s'inquiéter** un peu.
2. How is « aurait de quoi démoraliser » different in meaning from saying « pourrait démoraliser »?

   > La situation **pourrait démoraliser** n'importe quel scientifique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a subtle difference in the meanings of these sentences.

They both express an hypothetical situation. In the first case that situation **has the potential** to demoralize scientists but not necessarily will while in the second one, the situation should it happen **will** demoralize them.

*Avoir de quoi* is also often used in situation where the hypothesis is more unlikely to materialize, e.g. *Il y **a** là **de quoi faire exploser** une voiture* would be used when the explosion has little chance to happen while *ce qu'il y a là **pourrait faire exploser** une voiture* is a serious warning. Thanks Yohann V. for the suggestion.

Update:

1. Yes, there are based on the same pattern.
2. Beyond what I previously wrote about **avoir de quoi**, there is no fundamental difference in meaning between them.

Comment: *aurait de quoi + verb* is often used to say it is not happening. For Update : 2.) You may underline it is the tense that bring the *not-necessarly* idea

Comment: @YohannV. You are right, answer updated, thanks.